# Automatically delete posts based on query

Tags: functions, meta-value

I'm trying to delete certain posts (of a custom post type) automatically based on a comparison between the current time and a number of hours previous to now, for example 24 hours. 
The custom post type is appointments, and if an appointment is less than 24 hours in the future, and holds a meta_value of 'available' in the meta_key 'app_status', I want to delete it. The below code is what I'm trying, but it's not working. Posts that I have set with an app_date_start of less than 24 hours from now do not delete. I've tried different hooks to attach it to with no luck as well.

```
function delete_unclaimed_apps () {
    $avail = array(
        'post_type' => 'appointment',
        'meta_key' => 'app_status',
        'meta_value' => 'available',
    );
    $availapps = get_posts($avail);
    $now = (time()-(7*60*60));
    $cutoff = (get_field('minimum_reserve_notice', 'options') * 60 * 60);
    foreach ($availapps as $post) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $appid = get_the_ID();
        if (get_post_meta($appid, 'app_date_start', true)) {
            if (get_post_meta($appid, 'app_date_start', true) < ($now + $cutoff)) {
                wp_delete_post($appid, false); 
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'delete_unclaimed_apps');
```

Comment: try with init hook . code will be like this add_action('init', 'delete_unclaimed_apps');

Comment: Can you check that get_field('minimum_reserve_notice', 'options') is returning the correct value? Also change this line little bit **if ( (int) get_post_meta($appid, 'app_date_start', true) < ($now + $cutoff))**

Comment: The variable definitely has the correct value, I tested it. Even when I hard-code the value in it doesn't seem to work. I tried adding (int) as well, with now luck.
I did a little more testing and the function is firing correctly when I first create a new post. If I give it a past date when creating it, it will automatically delete it, just not any other time.

Comment: What is the date format stored in `app_date_start()`?

Comment: I figured it out after deciding to re-write the function from scratch, which I've found can sometimes help find something I've missed, which I did. Answer below, and thanks for your help attempts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with: Basically, I had the logic of the timing at the bottom wrong. Figuring out times and dates and what note is hard...

```
add_action('init', 'delete_unclaimed_apps');
function delete_unclaimed_apps() {
    $availapps = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'appointment', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array (
            array(
                'key' => 'app_status',
                'value' => 'available',
            ),
        ),
    ));
    foreach ($availapps as $post) {
            $timestamp = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'app_timestamp', true);
            $now = time() - (7*60*60);
            $cutoff = (get_field('minimum_reserve_notice', 'options') * 60 * 60);
            if ($now > ($timestamp - $cutoff)) {
                wp_trash_post($post->ID);
            }
    }
}
```